# Bootstrap 4 Flexbox my-auto Issue on IE11

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some text and a small carousel within a div to center vertically and horizontally using flexbox in Bootstrap 4. It works on all browsers, except for IE11 where the elements don't center, and my-auto doesn't seems to work there.

I tried through a lot of the other questions on here and elsewhere, yet none seem to solve the problem (at the time).

SCSS:

```
$motto: "Kaushan Script", sans-serif;
$general: "Muli", sans-serif;

$primaryColor: #ff3a3a;
$secondaryColor: #ff893a;
$auxiliaryColor: #fcff7f;

$pointOne: #fcd579;
$pointTwo: #e45a30;
$pointThree: $primaryColor;

.leading-points {
  height: auto;
  width: 90%;

  div.leading-point-one {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #FF1744;
    color: white;

    p {
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 1.25em;
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<section class="leading-points col-10 px-0" id="leadingPoints">
<div class="leading-point-one d-flex flex-column flex-md-row my-auto">
  <div class="col-md-7 text-left ml-md-3 px-0 my-auto">
    <h1 class="font-weight-bold">ALACRITOUS SPORTIES</h1>
    <p>Enjoy a wealth of options to choose from our carefully-assorted
      collection of sportscars.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-5 my-auto">
    <div id="lp1ImgCarousel" class="carousel carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="false">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="./images/lp1ImgA.png" alt="Ferrari Logo">
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="./images/lp1ImgB.png" alt="Ferrari Logo">
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="./images/lp1ImgC.png" alt="Ferrari Logo">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cgny8bkp/

All I need is centering those elements within the colored div on IE11.
Hopefully this isn't a duplicate; Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying CSS seems to do the trick :|

SCSS:

```
.leading-points {
  height: auto;
  width: 90%;

  div.leading-point-one {
    padding: 7.5% 2%;
    background-color: #FF1744;
    color: white;

    p {
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 1.25em;
    }
  }
}
```